# nested v-for loop in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have the the data in the following format.
[image]

```js
orders: [{
  _id: '',
  products: [
    _id: '',
    product: {
      title: '',
      price: ''
    }
  ],
  user: {
    name: '',
    email: ''
  }
}]
```

I want to show the products data from `orders[index].products[index]` in the table row in my Vue template for which I have to use 2 for-loops in nested form.

```html
<tbody>
  <template v-for="(item, index) of orders" :key="index">
  <tr v-for="(prod, j) of item.products" :key="j">
    <td>{{prod.name}}</td>
    <td>$price</td>
    <td>
      qty
    </td>
  </tr>
  </template>
</tbody>
```

With the above code I get error that template cannot be keyed. What would best way to achieve the solution?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Comment: Yes, you can not put :key attribute to template, use div or other html element instead.

Comment: For your case, I'd go with multiple tbody (put v-for in tbody), or separated table for each order.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an error in you're *orders* list. You can change the list to contain a list of product which is then accessible through the *v-for* mapping.

Order list:

```
orders: [
  {
    _id: "0132asd943",
    products: [
      {
        _id: "3i412e39",
        title: "Porduct 1",
        price: "239"
      },
      {
        _id: "kad83423",
        title: "Porduct 2",
        price: "699"
      }
    ],
    user: {
      name: "user1",
      email: "user1@mail.com"
    }
  }
]
```

Mapping:

```
<div v-for="item in orders" v-bind:key="item.id">
  <li>{{item.products[0]}}</li>
  <li>{{item.products[1]}}</li>
</div>
```

Working example:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-sara-9ps9b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

As the Vue warning indicated, `<template>`s cannot be keyed. The key needs to be on the `<template>`'s root children (i.e., `<tr>` in this case). Since the root child (`<tr>`) is already keyed, you don't need to apply another key.

The solution here is simply to remove the key from `<template>`. Also, note that the inner `v-for` iterates `orders[].products[]`, each of which contains an `id` field, which would be a better key than the index because of the `id`'s uniqueness.

```html
<tbody>
  <!-- BEFORE: -->
  <!-- <template v-for="(item, index) of orders" :key="index"> -->
  <template v-for="(item, index) of orders">

    <!-- BEFORE: -->
    <!-- <tr v-for="(prod, j) of item.products" :key="j"> -->
    <tr v-for="(prod, j) of item.products" :key="prod.id">
    
    ...

    </tr>
  </template>
</tbody>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ZEWJqvz?editors=1010)